# Virtualisation Error - Docker but Nested VT-x is enabled

Tags: virtualization, docker, oracle, compatibility

I have been trying to install Docker Desktop following all the steps from installing Docker hub to then installing Docker Desktop. I even got the final error of

> N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root, as file

However when I try to open Docker Desktop, I receive this error. I have enabled Nested VT-x/AMD-v on my virtual VM so I am not sure why I receive a Virtualisation Support error.

This is my first time using Ubuntu, so therefore please clarify if I have taken any missteps to cause this error and if so, how do you propose on fixing this issue?

[Error received when trying to open Docker Desktop on Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZIzF.png)

Thank you